# Custom Option Images

Tags: custom-options

Is there any way to get images next to the custom options for a product.

I have created a new custom layout for a product. Is there anyway to edit this template to hack in images next to individual custom options

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Custom options are rendered by their render type (think form fields for `text`, `select`, `file`, etc.). You'll find these phtml files in `template/catalog/product/view/options/type/`

If you need more info, share some details about where the images are coming from, or what custom options your using, etc.

Comment: I found a way to kind of acheive what i wanted, using CSS and JS. By injecting images before the options


    jQuery('#options_4_2').before('<img src="myimage.jpg">');

Not sure it is the best way but it got me the outcome. Thanks for the help

Comment: @eleven11 make this an answer and mark as accepted